# SQL Server Datetime not properly displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I created the query for the FirstIN and LastOUT of the employee for the past week of specified dates: July 1 - 8, 2018. Here is my query:

```
select  
        CredentialId,
        Value as Department,
        UID1FirstName +' '+ UID1LastName as EmployeeName,
        FIRSTIN, LASTOUT,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, FIRSTIN, LASTOUT) as NUMBEROFHOURS from 
(
    select 
        CAST(dtDate as date) as LogDate,
        MIN(CASE when ReaderName like '%ENTRY%' then dtDate END) as FIRSTIN,
        MAX(CASE when ReaderName like '%EXIT%' then dtDate END) as LASTOUT,
        CredentialId, 
        UID1FirstName,
        UID1LastName,
        Value

    from Log_Transactions

    inner join UserCredentials on UID1 = CredentialId
    inner join UserDefinedFields on HostUserId = UserID

    where dtDate between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-08' and  --EDIT DATES INSIDE, FORMATTED AS YY-MM-DD
            UID1FirstName like '%JASTINE%' and              --EDIT NAME INSIDE THE PERCENT SYMBOLS
            Event = '2000' and FieldNo = '1'

    group by
          CAST(dtDate as DATE), CredentialId, UID1FirstName, UID1LastName, Value
)
as DT;
```

And here is the result of that query:

[image: SEE RESULT HERE]

My problem is when I entered the dtDate of the person and converted the datetime to time only to view easily the records of FirstIN and LastOUT, the values of FirstIN and LastOUT are displayed many and other outputs into NULL

So, here is the added query:

```
select  
        CredentialId,
        Value as Department,
        UID1FirstName +' '+ UID1LastName as EmployeeName,
        convert(varchar(18), dtDate,1) as LogDATE,
        FIRSTIN, LASTOUT,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, FIRSTIN, LASTOUT) as NUMBEROFHOURS from 
(
    select 
        CAST(dtDate as date) as LogDate,
        MIN(CASE when ReaderName like '%ENTRY%' then convert(varchar(18), dtDate,108) END) as FIRSTIN,
        MAX(CASE when ReaderName like '%EXIT%' then convert(varchar(18), dtDate,108) END) as LASTOUT,
        CredentialId, 
        UID1FirstName,
        UID1LastName,
        Value,
        dtDate

    from Log_Transactions

    inner join UserCredentials on UID1 = CredentialId
    inner join UserDefinedFields on HostUserId = UserID

    where dtDate between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-08' and  --EDIT DATES INSIDE, FORMATTED AS YY-MM-DD
            UID1FirstName like '%JASTINE%' and              --EDIT NAME INSIDE THE PERCENT SYMBOLS
            Event = '2000' and FieldNo = '1'

    group by
          CAST(dtDate as DATE), CredentialId, UID1FirstName, UID1LastName, Value, dtDate
)
as DT;
```

And here is the result of added query:

[image: SEE RESULT OF ADDED QUERY]

HERE IS THE SAMPLE OUTPUT THAT I WANT TO PRODUCE:

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT I WANT]

THANKS FOR ALL OF YOUR HELP!

Comment: What is the qustion? you changed the group by and that is what you get. Why would you actually do that, and not keep the initial query intact and wrap it in another select to change the field formatting?

Comment: Do you have Reader name like Entry or Exit on the same row ? If not your End condition for Case will always return null of either of the columns First In or First Out.

Comment: Yes. I have a ReaderName of Entry and Exit on every row according to date and time.

Comment: When I add the dtDate to Group by it will not display the minimum and maximum time instead it shows all the results depending on the condition but when I removed the dtDate on group by, it shows an error like: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Column 'Log_Transactions.dtDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting on the outmost `SELECT` as the data from your subquery is correctly grouped and doesn't need additional transformations.

```
select  
        CredentialId,
        Value as Department,
        UID1FirstName +' '+ UID1LastName as EmployeeName,
        CONVERT(DATE, FIRSTIN) AS LogDATE,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(18), FIRSTIN, 108) AS FIRSTIN,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(18), LASTOUT, 108) AS LASTOUT,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, FIRSTIN, LASTOUT) as NUMBEROFHOURS from 
(
    select 
        CAST(dtDate as date) as LogDate,
        MIN(CASE when ReaderName like '%ENTRY%' then dtDate END) as FIRSTIN,
        MAX(CASE when ReaderName like '%EXIT%' then dtDate END) as LASTOUT,
        CredentialId, 
        UID1FirstName,
        UID1LastName,
        Value

    from Log_Transactions

    inner join UserCredentials on UID1 = CredentialId
    inner join UserDefinedFields on HostUserId = UserID

    where dtDate between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-08' and  --EDIT DATES INSIDE, FORMATTED AS YY-MM-DD
            UID1FirstName like '%JASTINE%' and              --EDIT NAME INSIDE THE PERCENT SYMBOLS
            Event = '2000' and FieldNo = '1'

    group by
          CAST(dtDate as DATE), CredentialId, UID1FirstName, UID1LastName, Value
)
as DT;
```